# Run Query in Siebel on Modified due date

Tags: date, date-modified

I want to run a query for open SRs by Modified due dates. I cannot find that field in normal query.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query open SRs on last modified date then the system field to use is "**Updated**" which is based on column "**LAST_UPD**". If you get any error then you can create a new custom BC field based on same column.
On the other hand, if you want to query based on Due Date then you should use field "**Commit Time**" which is based on column "**EXP_CLOSE_DT**".

BC: **Service Request**
Table: **S_SRV_REQ**